# How to bubble up validation error from child control to parent control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, custom-controls, custom-validators

My asp.net webform page has a user control (**Control1**.ascx) and a Save button. Control1 contains another user control **Control2**.ascx that contains several custom validators.

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
 if (somecheck1)
     args.IsValid = false;
 else
     args.IsValid = true;
}

protected void CustomValidator2_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
 if (somecheck2)
     args.IsValid = false;
 else
     args.IsValid = true;
}
```

I don’t want Control1.Save code to execute if any of the validators on **Control2** fails. How can this be accomplished? I am thinking about adding a **Valid** property on **Control2** and check for that in the Save button code. Does that reasonable approach? Also what should be done in the **Valid** property?

EDIT: Thanks for the response but I am not been able to work this out. I have posted a different question with more specific code examples at [Handling of validation errors from child controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649485/handling-of-validation-errors-from-child-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `page.validate("customValidator1");` where customValidator1 is your validation group. Then fire a `Page.IsValid();`If the first group validation fails then Page.IsValid() will return false. Implement this in your logic.